# Prove by using properties of sequence and its subsequence

Tags: limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove that $a^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for $\mid a\mid\lt1$

This is what I did:

$\mid a\mid\lt1$ so $\mid a\mid^n\lt1$

Write $\mid a\mid^n$ as a fraction, then $\mid a\mid^n= \frac{1}{\mid1+x\mid^n}$ for some $x\gt0$.

Then $\mid\mid a\mid^n-0\mid=\mid a\mid^n=\frac{1}{\mid1+x\mid^n}\leq\frac{1}{1+nx}\lt\frac{1}{nx}$

Given $\epsilon\gt0$, $\mid\mid a\mid^n-0\mid\lt\epsilon\space \forall\space n\gt\frac{1}{x\epsilon}$

Therefore lim$_{n\to\infty}\mid a\mid^n=0$

Note that -$\mid a\mid^n\leq a^n\leq\mid a\mid^n$ and lim$_{n\to\infty}$-$\mid a\mid^n=-$lim$_{n\to\infty}\mid a\mid^n=0$

By Sandwich Theorem, we have lim$_{n\to\infty}a^n=0$.

Can someone please verify my proof? Many thanks.

Comment: It is OK if you explain how you write $|a|$ as $\frac  1 {|1+x|}$ with $x>0$

Comment: I think it will be easier using $a^n = e^{n \ln a}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My mistake, should be $x\lt-2,x\gt0$ so that $\mid a\mid$ is smaller than 1

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is correct. You can easily say that any number which satisfies the condition $|a|<1$, and different than zero, converges to zero when its power goes infinity.
which means that;
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{t})^n = \frac{1^n}{t^n}= \frac{1}{\infty}=0,\hspace{0.3cm} \forall \hspace{0.2cm} |t|> 1$$